# Azure Blob timeouts after encryption was applied

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I started **encrypting** my Azure blobs. Now I am **occasionally** getting **500 - The request timed out** on blob operations (on both downloading and uploading blobs) after the request halts for about 30 seconds or so. After one of these timeouts, no other blob operation will work through the app, **unless I restart my Azure website**. Once restarted, everything runs as expected for a while.

**Example**: If I access an encrypted image through my application (I'm using the WebAPI to pull it and display it to the user) it shows up fine, but then if I try and access the same file hours later, the request halts and eventually times out. After that, I get the same issue while accessing any other file through my web app. However, if I access the direct url of the blob, then I can access the file (even though it's encrypted and therefore useless).

I cannot say with certainty what is causing this and when would the issue start occurring as I am not the only person accessing the app, so there's a good chance that the issue might have started before my failed request. Also, I never had issues as such before encryption was applied, nor did I have issues while testing encryption locally.

Any idea why this is happening, or maybe how can I prevent this? I am attaching my code below if it helps:

```
    public async Task<Tuple<string, string>> UploadToStorage(CloudBlobContainer container, Stream stream, string reference, string contentType, byte[] byteArray = null) {
        var blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(reference);
        blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = contentType;

        var cloudResolver = new KeyVaultKeyResolver(GetToken);
        var rsa = await cloudResolver.ResolveKeyAsync(new BlobConfig().BlobKeyVault, CancellationToken.None);
        var policy = new BlobEncryptionPolicy(rsa, null);
        var options = new BlobRequestOptions { EncryptionPolicy = policy };

        if (byteArray != null) blockBlob.UploadFromByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length, null, options);
        else blockBlob.UploadFromStream(stream, stream.Length, null, options);

        return Tuple.Create(new Config().BaseUrl + "/api/blobs/" + container.Name + "/" + reference, blockBlob.Properties.ContentType);
    }

    public BlobDto DownloadBlob(string container, string filename) {
        var account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(new BlobConfig().StorageConnectionString);
        var blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        var blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(container);
        var blob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(filename);

        var cloudResolver = new KeyVaultKeyResolver(GetToken);
        var policy = new BlobEncryptionPolicy(null, cloudResolver);
        var options = new BlobRequestOptions { EncryptionPolicy = policy };

        var m = new MemoryStream();
        blob.DownloadToStream(m, null, options);

        return new BlobDto { Blob = m.ToArray(), BlobContentType = blob.Properties.ContentType };
    }

    private async static Task<string> GetToken(string authority, string resource, string scope) {
        var config = new BlobConfig();
        var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(config.BlobClientId, config.BlobClientSecret);

        var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
        var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientCredential);

        if (result == null) throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the access token");

        return result.AccessToken;
    }
```

Comment: Why isn't `UploadToStorage` async? - ....GetAwaiter().GetResult()

Comment: I've updated the code with the suggested tweak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced all the synchronous blob related calls with asynchronous calls, particularly the downloading call. Also changed from stream to bytearray, but I don't think that's relevant:

```
await blob.DownloadToByteArrayAsync(byteArray, 0, null, options, null);
```